# How to update Thomson's TG585 v7 Firmware using Telnet

Tags: router, modem, firmware, telnet

The Thomson upgrade tool isn't detecting my router, I tried many times by disabling the Firewall as suggested, but yet it's not being detected, it worked only once, I upgraded to 8.2.4.11, but I lost Parental Control option and I need to get it back by downgrading to 7.something, like I said the upgrade tool is giving me a hard time trying to detect my modem, so I'm wondering if I downgrade using Telnet, or if there's an option which simply restores my default firmware.